# What is this dynamics book that has questions and it's solutions?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, soft-question, education, specific-reference

I found these questions online and was amazed by how organized this book was so it would be really helpful to know it's name

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Engineering Mechanics: Dynamics](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Engineering-Mechanics-Dynamics-Russell-Hibbeler/dp/0132911272) by Russell C. Hibbeler. In my 13th edition the problem is 12.174 on page 77. However I think what your picture shows is the solutions manual that accompanies the book. The solutions manual for the 14th edition is [available on archive.org here](https://archive.org/details/Hibbeler14thDynamicsSolutionManual/page/n179/mode/2up) and that matches the picture you show so I'd guess you have the 14th edition.